# Need advice on the safety of my commit and merge workflow

Tags: git

I am working in a local branch, and when I am ready to commit and merge, i run the following command:

`git commit -am <MY COMMIT MESSAGE> && git push && git checkout master && git pull && git merge <MY BRANCH> && git push && git checkout <MY BRANCH>`

This feels a bit amateur, and being pretty limited in my knowledge and skills with **GIT** I wanted to ask for advice on whether my command is safe and if not, a better way to accomplish this. Basically I want to merge my branch to ***origin/master*** then switch back to my local branch

Answer (score 1):

Here is some feedback which may be helpful:

- Using the -a flag on commit automatically stages ALL changes locally. You may have changes which you do not wish to commit. You could assume that you manually stage changes you would like to commit before doing the commit/push etc. by not using the -a flag.
- Chaining the push adn checkout commands could cause an issue if someone else has pushed to origin before you pull (i.e. your push is rejected). The command may pass (even if rejected), and checkout will still occur (YMMV). Maybe link commit/push and then checkout/pull, into 2 commands
- A git merge could cause conflicts, which would stop the command from running. You also may want to run unit tests after the merge, but before pushing to origin.

Comment: Typically when push is rejected, `git push` seems to return exit code = 1. Will this not always happen? Can `git push` return exit code = 0, even if push was rejected?

Answer (score 1):

Here are my comments:

1. `git commit -am` will not add new files.
2. Your script doesn't check for errors. If any of the commands fails (e.g. merge conflict) it will just mindlessly trying to do the next step - you may and up in a confusing state.
3. If you **always** merge to master on commit what is the purpose of having the non-master branch. I'd say just work on **one** branch.

   **This is important** because it removes 5 steps (`&& git checkout master && git pull &&
   git merge <MY BRANCH> && git push && git checkout <MY BRANCH>`) and leaves only `git commit` and `git push`.

   If you have only two steps you don't need to 'automate' them.

---

RE: Comment

> we work in feature branches in the team. prior to the team growing to multiple people, i did just work on master – r3wt

In this case you should merge other people's changes into your feature branch before you merge your feature branch into master.

In a multi-person setup your script doesn't really add up. For example, how do you do code reviews? I recommend pull requests for merging into 'master' (which isn't git but many git repo hosting solutions provide this extra functionality).

Comment: we work in feature branches in the team. prior to the team growing to multiple people, i did just work on master